# How to use friend function when the class is written inside the namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend-function

I have created a class inside a namespace now the problem occurs when i would have to use or call the namespace, What could be the possible reason for compiler error ??

```
namespace name1    
{   
        class show   
    {   
        int a,b;   
        void accept_data(void);   
        void display_data(void);   
        friend void use_class(void);  
    };  
}
```

Compiler Errors -

test1.cpp: In function ‘void use_class()’:
test1.cpp:17:6: error: ‘void name1::show::accept_data()’ is private
test1.cpp:31:16: error: within this context
test1.cpp:24:6: error: ‘void name1::show::display_data()’ is private
test1.cpp:32:17: error: within this context

Comment: Where is `use_class` declared?

Comment: It is declared outside namespace

Comment: you need to tell us what the compiler error is

Comment: If I remove the namespace then the same program runs very easily

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a friend function using an unqualified identifier (like `use_class`), that declaration always names a member of the nearest enclosing namespace of the class in which the declaration appears. A previous declaration of the function does not have to be visible. This means that your declaration declares a function `void ::name1::use_class()` to be a friend of the class `::name1::show`.

If you want to declare a friend from a different namespace, you must use a qualified id.

E.g.

```
friend void ::use_class();
```

Note that unlike the unqualified case, a previous declaration of the function being befriended must be visible. e.g.

```
void use_class();
namespace name1 {
    class show {
    //...
    friend void ::use_class();
    //...
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this:

```
namespace name1    
{   
        class show   
    {   
        int a,b;   
        void accept_data(void);   
        void display_data(void);   
        friend void use_class(show&);  
    };  
}

void name1::use_class(name1::show& h)
{
h.a = 1;
h.b = 2;
}
```

and in main:

```
name1::show s;

name1::use_class(s);
```

I am not sure why your functions have void parameters and return values though.

UPDATE:

this compiles and works:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace name1    
{   
        class show   
    {   
        int a,b;   
        void accept_data(void);   
        void display_data(void);   
        friend void use_class();  
    };  
}

void name1::show::accept_data()
{
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
}

void name1::show::display_data()
{
}

void name1::use_class()
{
    show s;

    s.accept_data();
    s.display_data();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    name1::use_class();

    return 0;
}
```

But, if I write it like this:

```
void use_class()
{
    name1::show s;

    s.accept_data();
    s.display_data();
}
```

I get your error. Make sure your `use_class` is part of same namespace.

Comment: "have void parameters and return values though" Andrei What you want to convey with this ?????

Comment: @System_Coder:what data is accepted via 'void accept_data(void);' if the parameter is void? Are your accept/display function using cin/cout internally? Your 'use_class', what instance of 'show' is it using if its parameter is void? Do you create an instance of 'show' inside 'use_class'? What are you trying to do, since probably there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: I would create the instance of show in use_class and of course there are better ways to do this but why this is happening is what I wanna know

Comment: namespace name1    
{    
 class show    
 {
  int a,b;
  void accept_data(void);
  void display_data(void);

  friend void use_class(void);
 };
 
 void use_class(void);   
}

Comment: @System_Coder: because in one case use_class is defined and implemented as part of the name1 namespace, in the other it is part of the global namespace. Your class definition has an use_class friend in the name1 namespace, not in the global namespace.